# Removing duplicate in XSLT for node having multiple value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I have a sample XML which has duplicate node. Node 1 and Node3 with below temperature code and both values in FAH and CC are duplicate.
All value within row node needs to be checked to checked to termed it as duplicate node

```
     <row>
                <attr name="temperatureCode">STORADE</attr>
                <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                        <value qual="CC">20</value>
                </attrQualMany>
        </row>
```

This sample message is

```
<document>
<party>
    <gtin>1000909090</gtin>
    <pos>
        <attrGroupMany name="temperatureInformation">
            <row>
                <attr name="temperatureCode">STORADE</attr>
                <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                    <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                    <value qual="CC">20</value>
                </attrQualMany>
            </row>
            <row>
                <attr name="temperatureCode">HANDLING</attr>
                <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                    <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                    <value qual="CC">20</value>
                </attrQualMany>
            </row>
            <row>
                <attr name="temperatureCode">STORADE</attr>
                <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                    <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                    <value qual="CC">20</value>
                </attrQualMany>
            </row>
            <row>
                <attr name="temperatureCode">DUMMY</attr>
                <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                    <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                    <value qual="CC">20</value>
                </attrQualMany>
            </row>
        </attrGroupMany>
    </pos>
</party>
</document>
```

When I apply the below XSLT, it works and duplicate node is removed. The XSLT which I am using is

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="dummy" match="row" use="concat(attr[@name = 'temperatureCode'], '-', attrQualMany/value/@qual)"/>


<xsl:template match="document"> 
    <CatalogItem>
        <RelationshipData>
            <Relationship>
                <RelationType>temperatureInformation_details</RelationType>  
                <RelatedItems>      
                    <xsl:for-each select="party/pos/attrGroupMany[@name ='temperatureInformation']/row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('dummy', concat(attr[@name = 'temperatureCode'], '-', attrQualMany/value/@qual) ))]">                        
                        <RelatedItem>
                            <xsl:attribute name="referenceKey">
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat('temperatureInformation_details','-',attr[@name='temperatureCode'],'-',attrQualMany/@name,'-',attrQualMany/value/@qual,'-',attrQualMany/value,'-', position()    )"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </RelatedItem>


                    </xsl:for-each>

                </RelatedItems>
            </Relationship>
        </RelationshipData>
    </CatalogItem>

</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it checks only the first value in attrQualMany name="temperature" and not both the values under attrQualMany.

If the sample message as below and it doesn't work for it. It should give me 4 records in output but it is giving me 3 records.

```
    <document>
    <party>
        <gtin>1000909090</gtin>
        <pos>
            <attrGroupMany name="temperatureInformation">
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">STORADE</attr>
                    <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                        **<value qual="CC">20</value>**
                    </attrQualMany>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">HANDLING</attr>
                    <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                        <value qual="CC">20</value>
                    </attrQualMany>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">STORADE</attr>
                    <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                        **<value qual="CC">30</value>**
                    </attrQualMany>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <attr name="temperatureCode">DUMMY</attr>
                    <attrQualMany name="temperature">
                        <value qual="FAH">10</value>
                        <value qual="CC">20</value>
                    </attrQualMany>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </pos>
    </party>
    </document>
```

The correct expected output is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CatalogItem>
   <RelationshipData>
      <Relationship>
         <RelationType>temperatureInformation_details</RelationType>
         <RelatedItems>
            <RelatedItem referenceKey="temperatureInformation_details-STORADE-temperature-FAH-10-1" />      
            <RelatedItem referenceKey="temperatureInformation_details-HANDLING-temperature-FAH-10-2" />
            <RelatedItem referenceKey="temperatureInformation_details-STORADE-temperature-FAH-10-3" /> 
             <RelatedItem referenceKey="temperatureInformation_details-DUMMY-temperature-FAH-10-4" />

         </RelatedItems>
      </Relationship>
   </RelationshipData>
    </CatalogItem>
```

Any input, please let me know

Comment: "*When I apply the below XSLT, it works*" No, it doesn't. Your XSLT does not compile.

Comment: I have corrected it. Sorry,  It was copy paste issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group by three values, you must enumerate all three explicitly in the key:

```
<xsl:key name="grp" match="row" use="concat(attr[@name='temperatureCode'], '|', attrQualMany/value[@qual='FAH'], '|', attrQualMany/value[@qual='CC'])"/>
```

I suspect this could be shortened to:

```
<xsl:key name="grp" match="row" use="concat(attr, '|', attrQualMany/value[@qual='FAH'], '|', attrQualMany/value[@qual='CC'])"/>
```

---

### Added:

> The data can be changed under `<attrQualMany name="temperature">` both
>   for qual and its value. So I cannot hardcode to check the qual="FAH"
>   or qual="CC". Is there any generic way without hardcoding the vaues.

If - and only if - the structure of `attrQualMany` is identical for all rows in the processed document, you can define your key as:

```
<xsl:key name="grp" match="row" use="concat(attr[@name='temperatureCode'], '|', attrQualMany[@name='temperature'])"/>
```

By "*identical structure*" I mean that in every row `attrQualMany` contains the same `value` children, with the same `qual` attributes, listed in the same order.

If the above condition is not true, you will have to process the document in two stages: first, concatenate all the values by which you want to group into a single text value; then group the resulting node-set by the concatenated value.

Comment: The data can be changed under  <attrQualMany name="temperature"> both for qual and its value. So I cannot hardcode to check the qual="FAH" or qual="CC". Is there any generic way without hardcoding the vaues.

Comment: @Victor, will there always be the same, known number of `value` elements? Do you simply want to compare them by position to identify duplicates?

Comment: @Martin, The number of elements in value can be different. I want to concat all the value for all the element between <row> nodes and then determine duplicate.

Comment: @Victor The question is this: will all the rows in a single document have the same `value` elements (in `attrQualMany`), listed in the same order (as in your example, they all have FAH followed by CC, and nothing else)?

Comment: No. The order is not defined and even the value can be different. Sample value can be 
      <row>
     <attr name="temperatureCode">DUMMY</attr>
     <attrQualMany name="temperature">
      <value qual="ABC">10</value>
      <value qual="XYZ">20</value>
                                               <value qual="PQR">20</value>
     </attrQualMany>
    </row>

Comment: So I don't want to check to hardcode the value in code and check. i need to read the value and then check duplicates

Comment: Let me ask this again, because the difference in complexity is quite significant: I understand that the internal structure of `attrQualMany` can vary. However, the question is about rows **in the same document**. Can there be two sibling rows with different attributes in `attrQualMany`?

Comment: Attributes will be same inside two sibling rows, Only its value can differ.
Yes, seems to be complex as I am struggling from morning.

Comment: @Victor Is this question not answered now?